Is it normal for the CPU usage of a single core to be at 100% when running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Does that CPU chart look okay to you? (Yes, that is dpkg hanging but that's another story).
Update
Well, it has stopped happening now that I have backed off from using AMDGPU so this is purely an academic question now.

That "dpkg is hanging" is totally relevant to what you notice.
First of all, it doesn't look like it's hanging, but that it's in the process of building, which can take some time.
Secondly, dpkg --configure -a is a low-level command that, according to the dpkg manpage, does the following:

Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet configured.  If -a or
--pending is given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured packages are
configured.

[...]

Configuring consists of the following steps:

1.  Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back up the old conffiles, so that they
    can be restored if something goes wrong.

2.  Run postinst script, if provided by the package.

Will process triggers unless --no-triggers has been specified.


To ensure that the packages and configurations will be installed in the correct order, the command has to process the packages sequentially, so the process will run in a single core. Since the process runs in a single core, this core will show increased usage. This increased usage of a single core that dpkg runs on is what you observe in your System Monitor. Depending on other factors, such as the temperature of a core, the active core may change and dpkg will run in the new one. So you may also observe alternating single-core usage between multiple cores.
All in all, the CPU usage you observe is perfectly normal and nothing to worry about.
